# How can Wall Street take money from amateur day traders?

Tags: game-theory, economics

This question was not taken well where I originally asked, despite my best intentions. This is a game theory question about short term day trading. A little backround on day trading verse investing

- [Long term investment in stocks is not zero sum because the market grows](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14144/is-it-true-that-90-of-investors-lose-their-money/14148#14148)
- A common quote is "90% of day traders lose money." [For instance](https://www.quora.com/Do-90-of-day-traders-lose-money-because-I-have-been-trading-for-only-a-short-period-of-time-and-my-principal-has-increased-by-30-so-is-this-simply-beginners-luck)

It is often advised that although stock investing is good, day trading is bad and even negative sum as brokers and the government begins taking bigger cuts. However there is a small minority of compulsive day traders on Wall Street who are lucratively and reliably profitable (200000% gains). Some results are too eerie for me to believe it's luck.

If it doesn't cause a fundamental change in assessment, I'll suppose day trading is zero sum. Here is the question

> Suppose amateur day traders bet randomly. Then when they bet there's a 50% chance of the stock going up and them making money, or a 50% chance of the stock going down and them losing money.  How could an elite Wall Street trader take money from these random betters?

Comment: Information is asymmetric.  If all amateurs have no information advantage and some professionals do, money will flow from the amateurs to the pros.

Comment: There are two other issuess here: one is that the chances are likely not 50-50...The second is that if an amateur bets on one stock and reinvests the money next in a second stock, if one stock  goes up by 10%, the other  goes down by 10%, he loses money. No matter which one goes up/down.  In this sense it is NOT a zero sum game.

Comment: In a fair zero-sum game it's quite possible to have nearly all the participants lose money while one or two of them gains a huge amount.  That's what would happen in a lottery (if the government and lottery operators didn't take their cut).

Comment: One important determining factor is response time. Market is arbitrage free only asymptotically (in time). When an arbitrage opportunity appear, it will die down pretty quickly. The more processing power your have (in detecting the opportunity and react to it), the better chance you make money out of it. For ordinary folks, by the time you heard any news, the opportunity has passed.

Comment: Even if your expected gain on each day was positive, there are scenarios where your fortune would go to $0$ with probability $1$.  See e.g. my MaplePrimes application [Great Expectations](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=127116).  For those who don't have Maple, this can be run with the free [Maple Player](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/Mapleplayer/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various models in economics that can give you some answers.

As mentioned before, there would have to be some asymmetry of information for professionals to be able to exploit "amateurs", who have inferior information.

However, if these amateurs were rational, they should realize they have inferior information, and not trade, since they would lose money in expectation. This intuition is formalized by the "[no trade theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022053182900461)". It would seem, then, that these amateurs are not rational, for if they were rational, systematic losses would not be an equilibrium outcome (not trading is a profitable deviation).

There is a second class of models, "noisy rational expectations models", where rational traders with information exploit what is called "noise traders" (which might be a version of the amateurs you describe). The seminal paper in this literature is [this one](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1805228). In these models, the professional traders acquire information at a cost and use it to exploit the noise traders, making systematic profits while noise traders lose money. Grossman, one of the authors, started a hedge fund after his academic career and was quite successful, and his trading is rumored to be influenced by his model. Hence, it does seem to capture the essentials of what you are trying to understand.